# Is there a verb for 'to make negative'?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, negation

If I am instructing someone to make a number negative, is there a verb I can use?

Negitivise? Negify?
Negate, for me, does not work as this is to cancel out, rather than turn a number into the negative equivalent.

Comment: "Negate" is the word.  You're just used to hearing it in a different context.

Comment: @HotLicks Oxford Dictionaries Online give three meanings for *negate* the first of which is *to nullify - alcohol negates the effect of the drug*. None of the meanings relate to mathematics, and I would be disinclined to use it simply as a way of saying that the sign has changed from positive to negative. I don't believe it is used in that way, but I may be wrong.

Comment: @WS2 Talk to a mathematician.  Or a computer programmer.

Comment: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/negate

Comment: @WS2 That's exactly what I thought. None of the meanings listed mention making negative except in the sense of phrase (rather than numbers)

Comment: @Hot Licks For the sake of my need "Negate" gives the intended meaning. I get wary when thefreedictionary is given as a reference. The same way I do when Wikipedia is given as reference.

Comment: Be more wary when OED is the only "accepted" reference.

Comment: Fair point. I guess all dictionaries (and language) is "crowd-sourced", in a way!

Comment: One major problem with the "traditional" dictionaries is that, while they make an effort to add new words, the definitions of old words tend to become stagnant.  The whole concept of "negative numbers" (outside of math texts) is relatively new: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=negative+number&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnegative%20number%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @HotLicks As it happens I was not quoting the OED (its site is currently down), but the cheap and cheerful ODO (Oxford Dictionaries Online). When the OED is up and running I will check as to whether they have a mathematical sense for *negate*. That would be the type of matter for which I would be entirely happy to use the OED as the authority. (mathematical expressions do not get changed every day by every wind of fancy as though they were the names of pizza toppings!)

Comment: @HotLicks I have managed to get into the OED through a back-door process, whilst it is currently disabled. The verb *negate* is not listed with any mathematical sense. Clearly *negative* as an adjective is something else entirely.